# Moving imageview to another imageview with move animation not lining up correctly

Tags: android

I have two images inside of a constraint layout. I want to move the left image to the right and fall directly on top of the other. Both images are identical in size and position relatively. One on the right and one on the left. When I use the move animation it leaves the image slightly off.

Code:

```
Animation img = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, playerTwoCard.getLeft(), Animation.ABSOLUTE, playerTwoCard.getTop());
```

XML

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playerOneCardTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/club_ace" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playerTwoCardTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/spade_ace" />



    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to move one ImageView onto the another ImageView. Target ImageView and Destination Image View doesn't need to have the same width and height. My solution to achieve this is using ObjectAnimator.

First and foremost set up the AnimationViewTranslator like this.

```
public class AnimationViewTranslator {
private static final int DEFAULT_DURATION = 1000;
private static final int DEFAULT_DURATION_DISAPPEAR = 200;
private View mTarget;
private View mDest;

private float originX;
private float originY;
private float destX;
private float destY;

private int mCircleDuration = DEFAULT_DURATION;
private int mMoveDuration = DEFAULT_DURATION;
private int mDisappearDuration = DEFAULT_DURATION_DISAPPEAR;

private WeakReference<Activity> mContextReference;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private ImageView mImageView;
private Animator.AnimatorListener mAnimationListener;

public AnimationViewTranslator() {
}

public AnimationViewTranslator attachActivity(Activity activity) {
    mContextReference = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
    return this;
}

public AnimationViewTranslator setTargetView(View view) {
    mTarget = view;
    setOriginRect(mTarget.getWidth(), mTarget.getHeight());
    return this;
}

private AnimationViewTranslator setOriginRect(float x, float y) {
    originX = x;
    originY = y;
    return this;
}

private AnimationViewTranslator setDestRect(float x, float y) {
    destX = x;
    destY = y;
    return this;
}

public AnimationViewTranslator setDestView(View view) {
    mDest = view;
    setDestRect(mDest.getWidth(), mDest.getWidth());
    return this;
}

public AnimationViewTranslator setBorderWidth(int width) {
    mBorderWidth = width;
    return this;
}

public AnimationViewTranslator setBorderColor(int color) {
    mBorderColor = color;
    return this;
}

public AnimationViewTranslator setCircleDuration(int duration) {
    mCircleDuration = duration;
    return this;
}

public AnimationViewTranslator setMoveDuration(int duration) {
    mMoveDuration = duration;
    return this;
}

private boolean prepare() {
    if (mContextReference.get() != null) {
        ViewGroup decoreView = (ViewGroup) mContextReference.get().getWindow().getDecorView();

        mBitmap = drawViewToBitmap(mTarget, mTarget.getWidth(), mTarget.getHeight());
        if (mImageView == null)
            mImageView = new ImageView(mContextReference.get());
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

        int[] src = new int[2];
        mTarget.getLocationOnScreen(src);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(mTarget.getWidth(), mTarget.getHeight());
        params.setMargins(src[0], src[1], 0, 0);
        if (mImageView.getParent() == null)
            decoreView.addView(mImageView, params);
    }
    return true;
}

public void startAnimation() {

    if (prepare()) {
        getAvatarRevealAnimator().start();
    }
}

private AnimatorSet getAvatarRevealAnimator() {
    final float endRadius = Math.max(destX, destY) / 2;
    final float startRadius = Math.max(originX, originY);

    Animator mRevealAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "scaleX", startRadius, endRadius * 1.05f, endRadius * 0.9f, endRadius);
    mRevealAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    final float scaleFactor = 1.5f;
    Animator scaleAnimatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, View.SCALE_Y, 1, 1, scaleFactor, 1);
    Animator scaleAnimatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, View.SCALE_X, 1, 1, scaleFactor, 1);
    Animator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, View.ALPHA, 0, 1);

    AnimatorSet animatorCircleSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorCircleSet.setDuration(mCircleDuration);
    animatorCircleSet.playTogether(scaleAnimatorX, scaleAnimatorY, alphaAnimator);
    animatorCircleSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            if (mAnimationListener != null)
                mAnimationListener.onAnimationStart(animation);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            int[] src = new int[2];
            int[] dest = new int[2];
            mImageView.getLocationOnScreen(src);
            Log.i("SOURCE", src[0] + " " +src[1]);
            mDest.getLocationOnScreen(dest);

            float y = mImageView.getY();
            float x = mImageView.getX();
            Animator translatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, View.X, x, x + dest[0] - (src[0] + (originX * scaleFactor - 2 * endRadius * scaleFactor) / 2) + (0.5f * destX - scaleFactor * endRadius));
            translatorX.setInterpolator(new TimeInterpolator() {
                @Override
                public float getInterpolation(float input) {
                    return (float) (-Math.pow(input - 1, 2) + 1f);
                }
            });
            Animator translatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, View.Y, y, y + dest[1] - (src[1] + (originY * scaleFactor - 2 * endRadius * scaleFactor) / 2) + (0.5f * destY - scaleFactor * endRadius));
            translatorY.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

            AnimatorSet animatorMoveSet = new AnimatorSet();
            animatorMoveSet.playTogether(translatorX, translatorY);
            animatorMoveSet.setDuration(mMoveDuration);

            AnimatorSet animatorDisappearSet = new AnimatorSet();
            Animator disappearAnimatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, View.SCALE_Y, 1, 0);
            Animator disappearAnimatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, View.SCALE_X, 1, 0);
            Animator disappearAlphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, View.ALPHA, 1, 0);
            animatorDisappearSet.setDuration(mDisappearDuration);
            animatorDisappearSet.playTogether(disappearAnimatorX, disappearAnimatorY, disappearAlphaAnimator);


            AnimatorSet total = new AnimatorSet();
            total.playSequentially(animatorMoveSet, animatorDisappearSet);
            total.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    if (mAnimationListener != null)
                        mAnimationListener.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    reset();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
            total.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

    return animatorCircleSet;
}

private Bitmap drawViewToBitmap(View view, int width, int height) {
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable();
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(dest);
    drawable.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
    drawable.draw(c);
    view.draw(c);
    return dest;
}

private void reset() {
    mBitmap.recycle();
    mBitmap = null;
    if (mImageView.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup) mImageView.getParent()).removeView(mImageView);
    mImageView = null;
}

public AnimationViewTranslator setAnimationListener(Animator.AnimatorListener listener) {
    mAnimationListener = listener;
    return this;
}}
```

After setting up the AnimationViewTranslator, then use the animation like this.

```
new AnimationViewTranslator().attachActivity(activity).setTargetView(targetView).setMoveDuration(430).setDestView(destView).setAnimationListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    }).startAnimation();
```